# incorrect table name inserting into using Laravel Excel to Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm attemptng to insert relational data using the Laravel Excel concern ToCollection

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
```

however the query is attempting to insert into the table **objective_years** and not **objective_year**

**ObjectivesImport.php**

```
namespace App\Imports;
use App\Models\Objective;
use App\Models\ObjectiveYear;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;


class ObjectivesImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {

            $objectiveDetail =  Objective::create([
                  'description' => $row[0],
                  'guidance' => $row[1],
                  'team_id' => $row[2],
                  'subject_id' => $row[3],
            ]);

            $yearDetail =  ObjectiveYear::create([
                'objective_id' => $row[4],
                'year_id' => $row[5],

            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have two models with a many to many relatinship pivot.

**Objective**

```
class Objective extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'guidance','subject_id','team_id'
    ];

    public function years ()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Year');
    }

}
```

**Year**

```
class Year extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function objectives()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Objective')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**ObjectiveYear**

```
class ObjectiveYear extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'objective_id', 'year_id'
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```
class ImportController extends Controller
{
  public function getImport()
  {
      return view('import');
  }

  public function import()
  {
      Excel::import(new ObjectivesImport, request()->file('csv_file'));
      return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
  }
}
```

Comment: please check your table name in database laravel add call table from database with plural name. if it is not plural than add this code in model define table name protected $table = 'my_flights';

Comment: @umefarooq my db tables are named objectives, years and objective_year

Comment: objectives and years are fine s per your model name, but  you have to specify protected $table = 'objective_year'; in your Objective_Year Model as table name is not plural in database.

Comment: I see now thanks, I was to focussed on trying to understand why rather than just looking for a solution